# Tableau: View and/or edit Initial SQL of existing Redshift connections

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, tableau-api

I'm trying to view or edit the Initial SQL code that is being executed by an existing Tableau Server connection to Amazon Redshift, but I can't find the option for it. After considerable research online I still haven't been able to find the answer. Does anyone know if it is even possible to edit/view the SQL of existing Redshift connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have access to the Redshift environment. Within Tableau desktop, right click on the data source and select Create Local Copy. Pick a save as location as necessary. Right click again on the new local data source and select Edit Data Source.

Click on the data source to make the menu appear and select Initial SQL.

[image]